# Exit from application on Internet Error

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

I am using webapi-avplay to play video on samsung tizen tv web app. I am facing issue when I disconnect Internet from TV.

In web app, video is playing fine when there is no internet interruption. whereas when I disconnect internet from TV during video play then video buffers and instead of showing error popup it exit from application. I have written code for popup in 'error' section of avplay.

One more interesting thing is that sometime it works properly. Moreover we have no cable connection in TV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using **NetworkStateChangedCallback** ?

You have to use NetworkStateChangeListener for that.Try detecting the change in network state and take step accordingly.

```
function addNetworkStateChangeListener() {
    var onChange = function(data) {
        alert("Network State Changed");
        //do your code or show error popup
 }
  listenerID = webapis.network.addNetworkStateChangeListener(onChange);
}
```

For details implementation :
[Samsung D Forum : Tizen API Guide](https://www.samsungdforum.com/TizenApiGuide/tizen2821/index.html#Network-NetworkManager-addNetworkStateChangeListener)

Thank  you.

Comment: @
Armaan-Ul-Islam thanks for reply . could you please elaborate the how to use above code in application ?